# Makefile doesn't generate executable file

Tags: makefile, csh

I need makefile that is to copy the file to the name proj3 and change the prmission to make proj3 executable by everyone.
so far i have following code with error msg `proj3' is note up to date.

```
proj3:
        cp final proj3
        chmod 755 proj3
```

Comment: Your question is invalid. What results do you expect? What results current makefile have? What is make's output?

Comment: like i mentions, i want the executable file name proj3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(proj3):
        cp final proj3
        chmod 755 proj3
```

Comment: Err... what?  This won't do anything, ever.  If that's what you want, just don't run `make` at all.